# Adding multi language option in Android app

Tags: java, android, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have an application that fetches data from a server and displays it. Is there a way to convert the data from the server (which is in English) to whatever local the user has set on their device?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to do that. The server must send the same data in other languages too.

Answer (score 1):

The server **must** send your data in the language the app requests. For that you can use [google's translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/), on the client but preferably on the server(translate the content once), if you can't obtain the translations.

Beside that, all the labels etc. that are contained within the app can be translated locally. More info [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-at-runtime/).